# How to use .join?

Tags: python, error-handling, passwords, python-3.8, iterable

i have read on google , related to this. i do not understand what this means(can only join iterable).Please tell me how to fix this and from where should i read more about this

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

for letter in letters:
    letter_in_pass = random.sample(letters,nr_letters)

for symbol in symbols:
    symbol_in_pass = random.sample(symbols, nr_symbols)

for number in numbers:
    number_in_pass = random.sample(numbers, nr_numbers)
    
password_list = (letter_in_pass + symbol_in_pass + number_in_pass)
random_password = random.shuffle(password_list)


final_password = ' '.join(random_password)
print(final_password)



the error is this:
File "/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/python/JFF.py", line 24, in <module>
    final_password = ' '.join(random_password)
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

thank you

Comment: try printing out the `letter in pass`. It means that it can only join iterable as in it can only 'do' that function on iterable objects, such as lists or tuples. it says that  the `random_password` is not an iterable, so I'm thinking that the `password_list` is not an iterable

Comment: Just found out that it's because of the `random.shuffle(password_list)`. It doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

Random.Shuffle returns None when it has run it's manipulation on the state.

To fix your error you should use the password_list variable in the join function. The shuffle function does not return a list but instead changes the list in the memory.

```
final_password = ' '.join(password_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as MSpruijt said, the `random.shuffle(password_list)` doesn't return anything, rather it just shuffles the `password_list`. So, you should do the following:

```py
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

for letter in letters:
    letter_in_pass = random.sample(letters,nr_letters)

for symbol in symbols:
    symbol_in_pass = random.sample(symbols, nr_symbols)

for number in numbers:
    number_in_pass = random.sample(numbers, nr_numbers)
    
password_list = (letter_in_pass + symbol_in_pass + number_in_pass)
random.shuffle(password_list)


final_password = ' '.join(password_list)
print(final_password)



the error is this:
File "/Users/angadsinghbedi/Desktop/python/JFF.py", line 24, in <module>
    final_password = ' '.join(random_password)
TypeError: can only join an iterable
```

Comment: Thank you everyone, these tips were helpful and the code now works perfectly. Appreciate you all